# Detect and parse embedded video in html?

Tags: video, html-parsing, object-tag

I am working on a project which requires me to detect and extract the embed code of videos on a web page.

I know the `<object>` tag is used to embed videos, however, the specification says that it can also be used for other things like images.

So how do i deterministically know that an `<object>` tag contains a video within? or is there some other way to find this out?

Comment: are you talking about flash video?

Answer (score 1):

Historically, the `<object>` tag was intended to be used as a way to embed media such as video and audio in an HTML document. But as web video evolved, it turned out you can't provide a reasonable user experience without integrating video controls to your web app, and the de-facto standard for embedding video in an HTML was to embed a flash player (using `<embed>` or `<object>`) and to access the video from within that flash presentation. (In HTML5, you have the `<video>` object for that purpose, but I guess you don't have such control on the HTML files you need to process).

So usually, when you see an `<object>` element used for playing video, the object being referenced is actually an SWF - a **flash presentation** - which runs its own code that links to the video file. But a flash presentation may or may not contain a video, as well as many other things. So if you want to detect videos in `<object>`s, your options are

1. Have a list of all SWF files/URLs that are in fact video players. This method is easiest but bear in mind that you will have a lot of *false negatives*.
2. Programmatically evaluate the HTML you're parsing in a sandboxed browser, and detect the video from the screen capture. This is probably a huge effort but will solve your problem perfectly.
3. Download and decompile the SWF files referenced by the `object` tags, and implement a heuristic to figure out whether they contain an embedded video. I'm saying *heuristic* because an SWF is basically a program, and if you can figure out a deterministic method to know if a program plays video, you might as well try to figure out whether the program [halts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).